# QB twitter auth returns bad authentication on previously known good setup

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, token, quickblox

I have spent the last week verifying my build is setup correctly. i keep getting HTTP Status 422 from Quickblox with bad authentication data being returned as a result of . I know for certain that twitter auth is set up on my end correctly with peer reviews from colleagues who have verified this. We have determined from the stack trace below that the issue is not with the app but with quickblox services. What I need to know is has anyone else encountered this problem and have you found a solution yet. my next option will be to update the SDK but i suspect this is with the QuickBlox backend services.

```
16 19:39:52.545 18506-18922/saberapplications.pawpads D/QBASDK: =========================================================
                                                                   === REQUEST ==== 96667985-b234-446a-abf4-8cce40b9219f ===
                                                                   REQUEST
                                                                       POST https://api.quickblox.com/login.json
                                                                   HEADERS
                                                                       QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                                                       QB-SDK=Android 2.6.1
                                                                       QB-Token=<token is here>
                                                                   PARAMETERS
                                                                       provider=twitter
                                                                       keys[token]=<token is here>
                                                                       keys[secret]=<secret is here, no im not gonna show you all>
                                                                   INLINE
                                                                       POST https://api.quickblox.com/login.json?provider=twitter&keys[token]=<token goes here>&keys[secret]=<secret goes here, no im not gonna show you all>
06-16 19:39:53.156 18506-18922/saberapplications.pawpads D/QBASDK: *********************************************************
                                                                   *** RESPONSE *** 96667985-b234-446a-abf4-8cce40b9219f ***
                                                                   STATUS : 422 
                                                                   HEADERS
                                                                       X-Runtime=0.011606
                                                                       Cache-Control=no-cache
                                                                       QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                                                       X-Android-Selected-Protocol=http/1.1
                                                                       QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2017-06-16 18:39:52 +0000
                                                                       Status=422 Unprocessable Entity
                                                                       X-Request-Id=d065f378-5dc9-423d-91fc-fce4c28e2d30
                                                                       X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 422
                                                                       Connection=Close
                                                                       X-Android-Sent-Millis=1497631192829
                                                                       Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
                                                                       Date=Fri, 16 Jun 2017 16:39:53 GMT
                                                                       X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
                                                                       Server=openresty/1.9.15.1
                                                                       Content-Length=38
                                                                       Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000
                                                                       X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
                                                                       X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN
                                                                       X-Android-Received-Millis=1497631193154
                                                                       Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
                                                                   BODY
                                                                       '{"errors":["Bad Authentication data"]}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your report! We've localized the issue. Try to login please to check if it works now.